# Error during OIDC code flow: IllegalArgumentException: Passed URL is empty

Tags: wso2, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to do a simple login code flow from an Angular client with WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.
Service Provider is configured with Oauth/OpenID Connect Configuration.

First of all my client calls the `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint:

```
https://myplatform.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...
```

Then i get redirected to the login form page:

```
https://myplatform.com/authenticationendpoint/login.do?client_id=...
```

After entering username and password the user gets authenticated as I can see from logs (I also tried to log in with a wrong password and i get the Login Failed! message), but then I get an HTTP 500 message.

These are the network calls I see in the browser upon credentials submit:

```
1) https://myplatform.com/logincontext?sessionDataKey=a886baf0-2d20-4327-80c0-de723e14a420&relyingParty=i69JjSmHPUpQBJC3QDIzjltTHbQa&tenantDomain=carbon.super&_=1633447226722
2) https://poc.smartcityplatform.it/commonauth
3) https://poc.smartcityplatform.it/oauth2/authorize?sessionDataKey=d9948a51-80bf-4438-b0dc-be8eaefc1f56
```

WSO2IS logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Passed URL is empty.
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils.buildURLWithQueryParams(FrameworkUtils.java:1665)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.util.EndpointUtil.getErrorPageURL(EndpointUtil.java:413)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.expmapper.InvalidRequestExceptionMapper.buildErrorResponseConsentHandlingFailure(InvalidRequestExceptionMapper.java:174)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.expmapper.InvalidRequestExceptionMapper.toResponse(InvalidRequestExceptionMapper.java:138)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.expmapper.InvalidRequestExceptionMapper.toResponse(InvalidRequestExceptionMapper.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.convertFaultToResponse(ExceptionUtils.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.convertFaultToResponse(JAXRSUtils.java:1660)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.handleFault(JAXRSInvoker.java:362)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:210)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:225)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.filter.AuthorizationHeaderFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationHeaderFilter.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
```

Any idea of what is happening?
Thank you!

### UPDATE

I added more logging as suggested by user @Sajith, surprisingly I discovered that a table was missing in a DEBUG statement. I used deployment scripts from https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-is where statements about consent management tables are actually missing.

```
[2021-10-06 06:48:34,320] [921d87de-2dec-46c6-b1f5-84397fb2f8ad] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.expmapper.InvalidRequestExceptionMapper} - System Error while handling consent: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.exception.ConsentHandlingFailedException: Error while handling user consent for claim for user: sysadmin@carbon.super for client_id: i69JjSmHPUpQBJC3QDIzjltTHbQa of tenantDomain: carbon.super
....
    at 
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.exception.ConsentManagementServerException: Error while searching receipts.
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.util.ConsentUtils.handleServerException(ConsentUtils.java:64)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.dao.impl.ReceiptDAOImpl.searchReceipts(ReceiptDAOImpl.java:303)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.ConsentManagerImpl.searchReceipts(ConsentManagerImpl.java:637)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.ConsentManagerImpl.searchReceipts(ConsentManagerImpl.java:607)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.PrivilegedConsentManagerImpl$22.execute(PrivilegedConsentManagerImpl.java:562)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.PrivilegedConsentManagerImpl$22.execute(PrivilegedConsentManagerImpl.java:558)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.model.ConsentInterceptorTemplate.executeWith(ConsentInterceptorTemplate.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.PrivilegedConsentManagerImpl.searchReceipts(PrivilegedConsentManagerImpl.java:558)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.InterceptingConsentManager.searchReceipts(InterceptingConsentManager.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.consent.SSOConsentServiceImpl.getReceiptListOfUserForSP(SSOConsentServiceImpl.java:761)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.consent.SSOConsentServiceImpl.getConsentReceiptOfUser(SSOConsentServiceImpl.java:375)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.database.utils.jdbc.exceptions.DataAccessException: Error in performing Database query: '%s'SELECT R.CONSENT_RECEIPT_ID, R.LANGUAGE, R.PII_PRINCIPAL_ID, R.PRINCIPAL_TENANT_ID, R.STATE,RS.SP_DISPLAY_NAME,RS.SP_DESCRIPTION FROM CM_RECEIPT R INNER JOIN CM_RECEIPT_SP_ASSOC RS ON R.CONSENT_RECEIPT_ID=RS.CONSENT_RECEIPT_ID WHERE PII_PRINCIPAL_ID LIKE ? AND PRINCIPAL_TENANT_ID=? AND SP_NAME LIKE ? AND SP_TENANT_ID = ? AND STATE LIKE ? ORDER BY ID  ASC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
    at org.wso2.carbon.database.utils.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.executeQuery(JdbcTemplate.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.dao.impl.ReceiptDAOImpl.searchReceipt(ReceiptDAOImpl.java:338)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.dao.impl.ReceiptDAOImpl.searchReceipts(ReceiptDAOImpl.java:290)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'WSO2IS_IDENTITY_DB.CM_RECEIPT' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at
```

org.wso2.carbon.database.utils.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.executeQuery(JdbcTemplate.java:154)
... 84 more

Comment: The error you have seen has occurred while trying to build an error page URL. Hence the original issue seems to be hidden.

Comment: If you change the following line to DEBUG in log4j2.properties file, we will be able to get more insight into the issue with debug logs. `logger.org-wso2-carbon-identity.level=INFO`

Comment: I did what you suggested and I found the issue and I updated my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more logs, I found that a database table was missing. Strange that this came out from a DEBUG statement:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'WSO2IS_IDENTITY_DB.CM_RECEIPT' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at
```

I used Kubernetes to setup WSO2IS and used this script to initialize my database: https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-is/blob/master/simple/mysql-k8s/mysql-conf-db.yaml. Actually Consent tables are missing, they are available at WSO2IS folder installation, under `<WSO2IS_HOME>/dbscripts/consent` path.